# Records comparision between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that gives me the records from two tables in diferente databases. Something like:

```
SELECT 'SYST1', t1.Date, t1.Amount, t1.Document
FROM BD1.dbo.table1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SYST2', t2.Date, t2.Amount, t2.Document
FROM BD2.dbo.table2 t2
```

I need to add a column with the result of the comparison of these records upon the following assumptions:
1. Compare whether records with the same document and different system (there are only two systems)
2. If there are only two records in the previous conditions, present results in that column as follows (for each record):
Ok! - There are the same documents with different system and containing the same date and the same amount
Verify Date - There are the same documents with different system but different dates
Verify Amount - There are the same documents with different system but different amounts
Verify Date/Amount - There are the same documents with different system but different dates and amounts
Too many records – there are more than two documents

Any ideas?

Comment: What SQL flavor are you using? MS SQL Server?

Comment: I'm sorry: It's MS SQL Server.

Comment: You should set up a SQL Fiddle so you can get better results.